# Could someone create a `docker-compose` tag?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

The question at "[Why is one not allowed to use a Boolean in a docker-compose.yml?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/537/210)" is about docker-compose but there is not such a tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it yourself—simply type [docker-compose](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/docker-compose) into the tag entry box, and it will be created.

In private beta, creating tags only requires [1 reputation point](https://devops.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags). When we leave private beta and the privilege levels increase, it should be sufficient to leave a little notice at the end of the post asking for the tag to be added (or perhaps leave a comment).

In **public beta**, 150 reputation will be required, and after **graduation**, 300 rep is required (see [Reputation requirements compared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared/160292#160292) on Meta.SE).

Comment: Oh normally at least 300 rep is required right?

Comment: @030: Yes, it will be [150 reputation in public beta, and 300 past graduation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared/160292#160292).